# accessing User object in route

Tags: php, symfony1

I have the following route:

```
work:
  class: acWorkObjectRouteCollection
  options:
    prefix_path: /work
    module:      work
    model:       Work
    type:        object
    column:      workname
    model_methods:
      object: findBySlug
```

As you can see, this route pulls a Work object from the db by the `findBySlug` method and the slug column is `workname`. It all works fine, but i want it to pull the Work of the connected User, so if 2 users have the same work name, it will choose the right one.

something like: `->andWhere('w.user_id = ?', $this->getUser()->getId()` if you like..

of course, i can change the route url to `:username/work/:workname` but it looks less professional and it's not really necessary, since each user will only be able to edit his own Work.

Any ideas how to get this done? maybe if i could access the User object in the route i could do it, but i couldn't find out how..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's generally bad practice, I believe this is one of the rare cases when `sfContext::getInstance()` cannot be avoided. Use `sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()` in your `findBySlug` method.

Before using it please read [Why sfContext::getInstance() Is Bad](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/) so you're aware of it's problems.

Comment: Hmm.. so you think i shuold use the `/:username/work/:workname` route instead? I read the article and i didn't completely understand why it is bad, and I did managed to avoid using it in my project until now.. what do you say..?

Comment: I'd go with the `/work/:workname`, even though it uses `sfContext::getInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just edit proper file and append proper WHERE statement [using andWhere() of course] in code? This would be much easier.

AFAIR you can't access user data in symfony routes. Not automatically in YAML.

Edit:

I've haven't tried this, but have a look:

http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/85116/

If you'll come to something usable, please notify, I would like also to know [and change this answer as well]. ;]